# Allow string literals and JSON objects as as request at the same time

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm working on a route that I would like to receive (at some end-points) an JSON object (eg. `{data: "value1"}` ) and (in other end-points) a literal string (eg. `"value1"`).
I'm currently using express middleware "body-parser" as:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
.... some more code ...
```

Obviously, this only supports json objects handling.

The main doubt is, can I support receiving plain strings besides JSON objects?
If so, what would be the best way to do so?

PD: this is my first StackOverflow question, so please let me know if I can improve my question in any way.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is just `bodyParser.text()`, https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparsertextoptions

You use it in much the same way as `bodyParser.json()`, the key is to ensure that the request uses the correct `content-type` header so that the appropriate parser processes the request body. By default that would be `text/plain` for `bodyParser.text()`.

Comment: Actually, what I want to achieve is to have a specific end-point that receives a `text/html` request, I've missed the express documentation section where it points about this case (in the examples section) and tried something like this:

    router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    // Set the Json body parser middleware for all the end-points
    router.use(bodyParser.json());
    router.get('/', callback1)
    
    //Set the Text body parser middleware for this specific end-point
    router.post('/', bodyParser.text(), callback2);

Comment: But when I try consuming the (text) end-point, I get this error:
    Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
As if express was trying to parse the text as a Json object maybe?

Ps: I used Fiddler to get sure I sent the request in a correct format (text/plain)

Comment: @Wayrex I don't see anything obvious wrong with how you're using `bodyParser.text`. Is `#` the first character in your request body? Do you see the same error if you remove the `router.post` line for the `text` route? Try stripping everything back to isolate exactly what's causing the error. I'd also suggest studying the stack trace and digging into the Express source code, that can often prove very enlightening. When you say `in a correct format` you mean you checked the `content-type` header was set to `text/plain`?